# Exactly how much highway driving experience do I need for the "Declaration of Highway Driving Experience"?

Tags: driving-license, canada, ontario

I have a Dutch driving license, and to get an Ontario, Canada license, I can go straight to the G2 road test.  Among the requirements is that I need to complete and sign a “Declaration of Highway Driving Experience”, whece I indicate how much I have driven on highways with a speed limit of at least 80 km/h *in the past three months*.  I have quite a bit of such experience, *but not in the past three months*.  So, I will need to rent a car and drive around on highways, purely to meet this requirement.  This leads me to the question:

*In Ontario, Canada, exactly how much highway driving experience do I need to do the G2 test?*

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: @GregHewgill No, I have not (yet).  Should be a generic issue so perhaps someone knows already.  If not, I can ask and post the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked a local driving school, and they report that "enough" should be *15 to 20 trips* of *at least 5 km each*.  Driving back and forth to a destination 5 km away counts as two trips.